# How can I display "Out of Stock" on Products on Website automatically when Quantity on Hand is less than Zero?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, qweb

Hi, I am trying (in Odoo 10), if product quantity on hand is zero than show "Out of Stock" on Website.
Following code is working fine when I am logged in as Admin, but in case of normal website visitor it gives, "500: Internal Server Error"
Any solution Please?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtOeI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `qty_available` is a function field that calls the `_compute_quantities` method. This method accesses to different models, so when entering with no user or with one without the necessary permissions odoo raises `AccessError`.

To fix this problem, let's access the field through `sudo()`

```xml
<t t-if="product.sudo().qty_available &lt;= 0">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper out-of-stock" style="display: inherit !important;">
        <div class="ribbon btn btn-danger">Out of Stock</div>
    </div>
</t>
```